# Ember.js: Non-standard routing, need input please

Tags: ember.js

The application we're building will be comprised of several smaller sub applications.

```
/ <-- main application
/accounts <-- sub app
/reports <-- sub app
/contacts <-- sub app
```

We're going to utilize Django routing to direct the user to each of the sub applications. So when the user hits the main page of the site, it's pure Django. When they click to accounts it's pure Django. When the user lands on each of the sub app pages Ember will take over and go from there.

When a user visits the accounts subapp I transition the user into the accounts route:

```
Social.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('accounts');
    }
});
```

The URL for that looks like this:

```
/accounts/#/accounts/27
```

What I would like to do is load up the Account information when the user visits what is essentially the index page. This contains a list of accounts belonging to the user. When they select an account I want to link to the account route:

```
/accounts/#/account/27
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you add the code for your router mapping? Perhaps you can define the "account" route with a path like this: `this.route('account', { path: 'account/:account_id' });`

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did and it's working. That wasn't immediately clear when building out the app to begin with. Rewriting most of the code now while I can do it early. Voted you up, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a rootURL on the router and then the app will happily live in a subdirectory.

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('accounts');
});

Social.Router.reopen({
  location: 'hash',
  rootURL: '/accounts'
});

Social.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('accounts');
  }
});
```